# HTMX - Trigger event on clicking outside the modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, htmx

Here's my modal in my html:

```html
<div id="modals-here" class="modal modal-blur fade" style="display:none" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" hx-get="/referrallist" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#search-results">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
</div>
```

here's the serverside:

```js
app.get("/modal", (req, res) => {
    const html = `<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Add New Referral</h5>
                <button type="button" id="quit-modal" class="quit-modal hover:bg-blue-400 rounded" data-bs-dismiss="modal" hx-get="/referrallist"
                    hx-trigger="click">
                <img class="w-8" src="/images/cross-button.svg"/>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ${newReferral()}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`;

    res.send(html);
});
```

`newReferral()`  just makes a form, with a post request on the submit button. Nout fancy. What's funky is, when I'm typing in the modal... I can see its firing `/referrallist` in the background. Now I'm guessing that's because I'm clicking in the modal, which is clicking on `modals-here`, and it's registering the tab between elements as another click (I'm new in case you can't tell!).
The question is though, how exactly can I make `/referrallist` fire when someone clicks outside the modal (to close it)? I've got it firing on the X button just fine, nae worries. I tried adding a second event listener to the original one that fires `/referrallist`, which looked like:
`<div class="divide-y divide-gray-600" id="search-results" hx-get="/referrallist" hx-trigger="load, click from:#quit-modal>`
But that didn't work either, presumably because the `#quit-modal` div is only rendered after the `app.get("/modal"...` has fired.
Basically, I'm stumped. Any ideas of how I can do this?

I've been searching stackoverflow, reddit, YouTube and all sorts to try and find a solution. I'm not an advanced developer by any means, which could easily be the problem, but I've not managed to find or understand a solution yet.